# visualsearch.js - how to show facets onclick?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Yet another question on the most wonderful javascript plugin around: [visualsearch.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/)
 :-)

A feature which, according to my users feedback, is realy missing, is the possiblity to know, somehow, which are the available facets. My facets are many and it would be really nice to have a list of facets (maybe grouped) when clicking on the searchbox.

I had a look on the annotated source code, in particular to [search_parser.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/docs/search_parser.html) and to [search_box.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/docs/search_box.html).

I suppose that I've to trigger the click event on the element with `VS-search-inner` id. Or maybe another way would be to work on the parse function... I'm a little bit confused.

I also noticed the  `showFacetCategoryMenu`  which, unused at the moment, might implement the feature I'm searching for if modifyed.

So, in conclusion, my question are:

1. can anybody put me in the right direction?
2. which would be the right place to put my hands on, in order to implement the "show available facets" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that in the latest version of visualsearch.js (0.2.2) there is something similar to what I need:

```
  // Show a menu which adds pre-defined facets to the search box. This is unused for now.
  showFacetCategoryMenu : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this.facetCategoryMenu && this.facetCategoryMenu.modes.open == 'is') {
      return this.facetCategoryMenu.close();
    }

    var items = [
      {title: 'Account', onClick: _.bind(this.addFacet, this, 'account', '')},
      {title: 'Project', onClick: _.bind(this.addFacet, this, 'project', '')},
      {title: 'Filter', onClick: _.bind(this.addFacet, this, 'filter', '')},
      {title: 'Access', onClick: _.bind(this.addFacet, this, 'access', '')}
    ];

    var menu = this.facetCategoryMenu || (this.facetCategoryMenu = new dc.ui.Menu({
      items       : items,
      standalone  : true
    }));

    this.$('.VS-icon-search').after(menu.render().open().content);
    return false;
  }
```

Hoping this can help somebody else as well.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer from latest 0.3.0 code:

`showFacets: true`

> 0.3.0 September 20th, 2012 Add showFacets: true to your options to have all available facets automatically show up when the search text
>   box is focused. You can also pass multiple facet names to
>   withoutCategory, like so: searchQuery.withoutCategory('country',
>   'account').